# 1 if attribute exists, 0 otherwise

Tags: sql, oracle

In the following query, 1 is outputted for each attribute that is present in the 1 hour time interval:

```
select t1.attribute, count(*)
from table1 t1
where timestamp >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') and
      timestamp < trunc(sysdate, 'HH') and
      exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.attribute = t1.attribute)
group by t1.attribute;
```

How do I modify this to also output a 0 for each attribute that's not in the time interval?

Comment: You select all rows and make a `case when [where time conditions] 1 else 0 end` and remove that from the where clause? Please provide some sample data, I guess I dont understand your question.

Comment: Only table2 will always have a complete list of the attributes (no timestamps). The list in table1 will not be complete for each hour because some attributes might not be 'present' for a specific hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you state that `table2` has the full list of attributes. If that is the case then left join `table1` to `table2`:

```
select t2.attribute, count(t1.attribute)
from table2 t2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t1
        ON t2.attribute = t1.attribute 
        AND t1.timestamp >= trunc(sysdate-1/24, 'HH') 
        AND t1.timestamp < trunc(sysdate, 'HH')
group by t2.attribute;
```

Shifting your timestamp filters from the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause for the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` insures that those results in `table1` are truncated BEFORE performing the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will select all records from `table2` and ONLY those matching records from `table1` after the filter is applied.

Then counting the `t1.attribute` should give you a count or 0 like you want. Lastly performing the GROUP BY on the `t2.attribute` from your `SELECT` clause.